# Simple Bank application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to create a simple bank application form. This form is going to hold an array of 19 accounts objects. When the the user click the create button it create an account with an accountID and opening amount. When enter a an accountID and amount and click the deposit button it deposit money to that specific accountid. When the withdraw button is click it withdraws money from a specific account , when the accountid is specific. The balancebutton click gives you the balance of an account, when the accountid is specific.

here is my code..

```
public class Accounts
{ 

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }



    public decimal Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        Balance += amount;
        return Balance;
    }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        Balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

Here is code for the Form:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Bank
{
public partial class Bank : Form
{
    public Bank()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    Accounts[] arrayAccounts = new Accounts[19];

    decimal balance;

    private void createAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayAccounts.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayAccounts[i] = new Accounts();
        }



        double amount = Convert.ToDouble(amountTextBox.Text);
        int AccountId = Convert.ToInt32(accountIDTexTBox.Text);
        OutPutLabel.Text = "Account #" + AccountId + "Opened with Balance of $" + amount;


    }
    private void DepositRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double amount ;


    }

    private void WithdrawRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double amount;

    }

    private void exceuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void amountTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void balanceRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I really need help passing the accountid and amount into the array of objects. And writing the code for the depositButton , withdrwbutton and BalanceButton.

Comment: I think you had better use List<Accounts> and it's Add function instead of using array.

Comment: I am required to use only array of objects.

Comment: You can globally keep next index of the Account. You will increment it every time you add new one and always know when there is no place for new one.

Comment: how can i keep next index of the Account ?

Comment: Keep a variable (may be named "currentIndex" outside starting from -1 and as you create new account keep increment it before you create the account. If that reaches to 19 you have to handle what you may do.

Comment: Not related to your concerns but you really need error checking in some methods.  For instance, in `Deposit` and `Withdraw` there is nothing stopping the input `amount` from being negative.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd rename your DTO object to "Account".

Then the below should return a valid Account object if the Id exists in the array of Accounts if not it should return null, which then you should handle and tell user that "Account does not exist". If a valid Account object then make your appropriate method to withdraw or deposit or to get balance.

```
public Account GetAccount(int id)
{
  return arrayAccounts.Where(x => x.AccountId == id).FirstOrDefault();;
}
```

Comment: This is assuming your id uniqueness is controlled by your logic!

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how can you do your functions:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bank
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int _nextIndex = 0;
        private Account[] _accounts = new Account[19];

        private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIdTextBox.Text)) return;
            var account = new Account();
            int accountID;
            int balance=0;
            bool success=int.TryParse(accountIdTextBox.Text,out accountID);
            int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out balance);
            if(success)
            {
                account.AccountId = accountID;
                account.Balance = balance;
                _accounts[_nextIndex] = account;
                _nextIndex++;
            }
            resultLabel.Text = "Created Account: " + accountID + " with Balance " + balance;
        }
        private Account GetAccount(int id)
        {
            return _accounts.Where(x => x.AccountId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        private void depositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIdTextBox.Text)) return;
            int amount = 0;
            int accountID;
            bool success1 = int.TryParse(accountIdTextBox.Text, out accountID);
            bool success2 = int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out amount);
            if(success1 && success2 && amount >0)
            {
                var selectedAccount = GetAccount(accountID);
                selectedAccount.Balance += amount;
                resultLabel.Text = "Account: " + accountID + " balance get deposit for " + amount;
            }
        }

        private void withdrawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIdTextBox.Text)) return;
            int amount = 0;
            int accountID;
            bool success1 = int.TryParse(accountIdTextBox.Text, out accountID);
            bool success2 = int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out amount);
            if (success1 && success2 && amount > 0)
            {
                var selectedAccount = GetAccount(accountID);
                selectedAccount.Balance -= amount;
                resultLabel.Text = "Account: " + accountID + " balance withdrawed by " + amount;
            }
        }

        private void ballanceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIdTextBox.Text)) return;
            int amount = 0;
            int accountID;
            bool success1 = int.TryParse(accountIdTextBox.Text, out accountID);
            if (success1)
            {
                var selectedAccount = GetAccount(accountID);
                resultLabel.Text = "Account: " + accountID + ", Balance: " + selectedAccount.Balance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have renamed your class `Accounts` to `Account`

Comment: Thanks so much. The program is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

So I did somethings different. Im not quite sure what you wanted to see but here it goes. First I recreated your account like this:

```
public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }

        public Account(int accountID, decimal balance)
        {
            AccountId = accountID;
            Balance = balance;
        }

        public void Deposit(decimal amount)
        {
            Balance += amount;
        }

        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            Balance -= amount;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return AccountId + " " + Balance;
        }
```

Then I worked the form so it did not error and it did exactly what was described (the function Create, withdraw and deposit are all implemented).

```
public Bank()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private List<Account> arrayAccounts = new List<Account>();

        private void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Account account = new Account(arrayAccounts.Count + 1, Convert.ToDecimal(ammountTextBox.Text));
            arrayAccounts.Add(account);
            listBox1.Items.Add(account.ToString());
            OutputLabel.Text = "Account #" + account.AccountId + "Opened with Balance of $" + account.Balance;
        }

        private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    foreach (Account account in arrayAccounts)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ')[0]) == account.AccountId)
                        {
                            account.Deposit(Convert.ToDecimal(tbDeposit.Text));
                            refreshList();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select an account!");
                }
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter valid number");
            }
        }

        private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    foreach (Account account in arrayAccounts)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ')[0]) == account.AccountId)
                        {
                            account.Withdraw(Convert.ToDecimal(tbDeposit.Text));
                            refreshList();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select an account!");
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter valid number");
            }
        }

        private void refreshList()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach(Account account in arrayAccounts)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(account.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks so much , i will go through the code and give you feedback